# Help with Apex class querying the parent of a child record

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, class

I am trying to write a visual force page with extension to show the Parent records on a child record.  In this situation, many cases (custom child object) are associated with Products(parent lookup). Also, many parent products may have the same cases associated with them.

I can display the cases associated to products in the related list. But the use case requires the parent products to be visible at the child level.

controller code:

```
public class CaseParentExt {

    public List<L1dlF0rm0rg__ICIX_Product__c> prods {get;set;}

    public static L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c.Id caseId;

    public CaseParentExt()
    {
        //line 9:           
        prods = [ SELECT Id, Name FROM L1dlF0rm0rg__ICIX_Product__c where  Id = :caseId];
    }
    return prods.Id
}
```

Error I am receiving:

> Line 9: sObject type 'L1dlF0rm0rg__ICIX_Product__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: What package uses the namespace `L1dlF0rm0rg`? Are you sure the `ICIX_Product__c` object exists in that namespace? Also, the type for `caseId` should just be `Id`, not `L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c.Id`. Also, your `return` statement isn't contained within the scope of a function. Also, you don't have a semicolon terminating the line with the `return` statement.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ok, I have fixed a few things, the namespace issue, the sObject.Id issue, and the return terminating issue.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a lookup you can query the fields required directly:

```
[Select L1dlF0rm0rg__ICIX_Product__c, L1dlF0rm0rg__ICIX_Product__r.Name From Case Where Id = :caseId]
```

this gets you the ID and the Name.

Lookup fields from the parent are singular and not queried like related lists.

Comment: I have revised the select statement to reflect yours. Now I am getting the error Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c> on line 9: prods = [ SELECT L1dlF0rm0rg__ICIX_Product__c, L1dlF0rm0rg__ICIX_Product__r.Name FROM L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c where  Id = :prods.Id]; I am going to take a stab and say its because its a list and I need to just put it as public?

Comment: @Jason most likely because you are doing prods.id when prods is a list

Comment: I changed out the prods.Id to just prods, now I am getting an Invalid Bind expression? Invalid bind expression type of ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c for column of type Id Line 7 (Select Statement.)